# Distance with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Im not sure if the way i solve this problem is right.

Let
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1&-1 \\ 1&4\end{bmatrix}, W = Sp \{ \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1 \\ 1&2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&2\end{bmatrix} \}
$$

Find the distance between $A$ and $W$.

### My attempt

So what i did was to find the orthogonal projection of $A$ on $W$, call it $u_0$.

After that i calculated the distance using norms: $||A-u_0||$.

Firstly, using inner product i calculated the coefficients of the vectors for the linear combination for $u_0$:

$a_1 = (A,w_1) = 1*0 + (-1)(-1) + 1*1 + 4*2 = 10$

$a_2 = (A,w_2) = 1*1 + (-1)*0 + 1*0 + 4*2 = 9$

Therefore,  $u_0 = 10w_1 + 9w_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 9&-10 \\ 10&38\end{bmatrix}$

Now, calculate the distance from $A$ to $u_0$:

$$
||A-u_0|| = ||\begin{bmatrix} -8&-11 \\ -9&-34\end{bmatrix}|| = \sqrt{8^2+11^2+9^2+34^2}
$$

And its a very big number - did i do something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't $A=w_1+w_2$? In other words $A \in W$, which makes the distance $0$.

Comment: Good point, so why didnt i get $0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A=w_1+w_2$, $A\in W$ which means the distance is $0$. Note that using inner product like you did doesn't help to find the distance. Try to visualize these as vector additions and projections in 2D to understand what I mean.

In general, finding the distance can be reduced to least squares problem. Let us write the equation in vectorized form as
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 1&0 \\ -1&0 \\ 2&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2\end{bmatrix}$$
Mutiply from the left with $W^T$ you get
$$\begin{bmatrix}10 \\ 9\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}6&4 \\ 4&5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2\end{bmatrix}$$
which gives the solution $a_1=a_2=1$ and consequently $A=u_0$ as expected.

Notice how the inner product result you found appears on the left side. This inner product doesn't immediately gives the coefficients unless the base is orthonormal.